# How to set relative paths in dijit templates?

Tags: templates, dojo, relative-path

I've got a dijit widget that is, relative to dojo's root at the following location:

```
/modules/components/myWidget/template/MyWidget.html
```

Now, along with this template, I have an image file that needs to be included in the template as well:

```
/modules/components/myWidget/template/myImage.png
```

Now, in my template text:

```
<img src="./myImage.png" />
```

However, this resolves relative to the application root (neither dojo's root, neither the template location).

**How can I make it so that my template resolves directly to it location?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would do the following, make an attach point to the image, for example:

```html
<img src="" data-dojo-attach-point="imageNode" />
```

Then in your JavaScript code (for example in the `postCreate` function of your widget) I would do the following:

```js
declare([...], {
    postCreate: function() {
        this.imageNode.src = require.toUrl("./template/myImage.png");
    }
}
```

With `require.toUrl`, you actually get the URL as a result that would be used if you wish to load it as a module. This means that:

```js
require.toUrl("./template/myImage.png");
```

refers to the current module path (`./`) which is probably `/modules/components/myWidget`, and then `template/myImage.png`.

Comment: Is there any way in which you can do that directly from the template?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can put the `require.toUrl(...)` in a property and then use `<img src="${myProperty}" />`. This should work too, but you will always have that 1 line of code that retrieves your image URL.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I needed a relative path to my `dojo/text` template. e.g.

```
/foo
    /js
       /stuff
           SomeWidget.js
    /templates
       /MyTemplateForSomeWidget.html
```

It turns out you're supposed to give a "module path" not a "dumb url", and as such this **won't** work:

```
"dojo/text!../../templates/MyTemplateForSomeWidget.html"
```

It gives you the great error `IrrationalPath` (with no explanation). Turns out you're not allowed to use "`../`", so it freaks out. You can of course use an absolute path, by starting with a `/`, but in my case the whole path wasn't guaranteed, so I got around the issue by registering the path in my `dojoConfig`, like so

```
dojoConfig = {
    // ...
    packages: [
        { name: 'app', location: '/foo/js/app' },
        { name: 'templatePkg', location: '/foo/templates/' },
        // ... etc
    }
}
```

Then just refer to `templatePkg` as the beginning of your template path, like so:

```
"dojo/text!templatePkg/MyTemplateForSomeWidget.html"
```

The "hard part" for me was getting around the idea that a "package" had to be for JavaScript sources, and thought others might have the same misconception.

Hope this helps.
G.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the `require` method is brought like a module
2. Use `require.ToUrl("./relative/path")`

This next example is from production code at work, where I've cut out the extra stuff. Let's pretend the file is `app/widget/thingy.js`:

```
define([
    "require" // Needed for relative require.toUrl() calls
    /* stuff */
], function(require /*stuff*/){
    var blankImage = require.toUrl("../resources/transparent.gif");
    /* stuff */
});
```

When it runs, the `blankImage` value should be `"app/resources/transparent.gif"`.

Additionally, if you are using Dijits and `_WidgetBase`, you should also look into assigning the `require` value into the `contextRequire` property. This will allow you do do stuff like this in your HTML templates:

```
<div data-dojo-type="./SiblingWidget"></div>
```